# Statements blocking execution inside recursive function

Tags: c++

I am trying to get my head around recursion and have hit something that is causing me to scratch my head.

The following code executes as I would expect and allows me to watch `x` decrement until the base statement is met:

```
#include <iostream>

bool rec(int x);

int main() {
    rec(2);
    return 0;
}

bool rec(int x) {
    if (x == 0){
        return 0;
    }
        if(rec(x -1))
            return 1;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

However, if I add any kind of statement (`std::cout`, assignment, etc) then the code below my `if` statement becomes unreachable. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

bool rec(int x);

int main() {
    rec(2);
    return 0;
}

bool rec(int x) {
    if (x == 0){
        return 0;
    }
        if(rec(x -1))
            std::cout << "Blocking" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I do not understand why this is happening?

Note: This is a simplified version of the code where this issue was encountered, to be used as a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If you are going to use the `bool` type, you might as well use the Boolean constants: `true` and `false`. Don't use numbers with `bool` type.

Comment: Change your coding style.  **ALWAYS** use braces after `if` and `else`.  NO EXCEPTIONS.

Comment: Interesting mix of correct code versus wishful thinking python indenting. Always use braces for conditional code.

Comment: You might have warning about unreachable code. Else, increase your warning level.

Comment: You're assuming that indentation affects how the program behaves.  It doesn't.  The `return 1` in your second code sample is unaffected by the preceding `if`, so the two statements after it are never reached.   If you want the `return 1` to still be affected by the `if`, explicitly group statements using `{}` - for example,`if (rec(x - 1)) {std::cout << "Blocking" << std::endl; return 1;}`  (and, more or less, any amount you wish of indenting or other whitespace, since it has no effect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `if` statement (or other form of control flow) without braces treats only the following statement as part of its body. C++ is *not* indentation-sensitive and will not use the number of leading spaces to determine control flow.

So when you write

```
if (rec(x - 1))
  std::cout << "Blocking" << std::endl;
  return 1;
```

C++ reads it as

```
if (rec(x - 1)) {
  std::cout << "Blocking" << std::endl;
}
// Note: `return` is NOT in the if statement.
return 1;
```

The `return` always gets taken and exits your function early, before the rest of the code can execute.

Put braces around multi-line `if` statements.

```
if (rec(x - 1)) {
  std::cout << "Blocking" << std::endl;
  return 1;
}
```

In fact, most modern C++ style guides suggest always using braces, even for one-line conditionals, to avoid this exact confusion during refactoring.